# Pass tables through for-loop r

Tags: r, for-loop, datatables, lapply

Let's suppose that I have n tables : table_1, table_2, ..., table_n.
I want to create n matrices like below but I don't know how to do the same with a for-loop or lapply function :

```r
matrice_WS_1 = cbind(tab_1$WS) %*% rbind(tab_1$WS)
matrice_WS_2 = cbind(tab_2$WS) %*% rbind(tab_2$WS)
matrice_WS_3 = cbind(tab_3$WS) %*% rbind(tab_3$WS)
.
.
.
matrice_WS_n = cbind(tab_n$WS) %*% rbind(tab_n$WS)
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by calling `cbind` and `rbind` on the single `WS` column?

Comment: I try to create a matrix by multiplying a column by a row.

Answer (score 0):

Put the tables in a list, and iterate through:

```
tbl.list <- list(table_1, table_2, table_3, table_n)

mat.list <- setNames(
  vector(mode = "list", length = length(tbl.list)), 
  nm = paste0("matrix_WS_",1:length(tbl.list))
  )

for (i in 1:length(tbl.list)) {
  dat = tbl.list[[i]]["WS"] #retain two dimensions
  mat = as.matrix(dat) #convert to matrix
  out = mat %*% t(mat) #transform data as desired
  mat.list[[i]] <- out
}
```

Comment: why.... `assign` does reduce the need to write another line creating unwanted objects in the env

Comment: If that is the intended purpose, then the updated answer I suppose is a better result

Comment: interesting suggestion... in what way would this be an improvement?